# Accessing the default mongodb database through console

Tags: meteor, console

Started meteor+mongodb yesterday so probably it is a simple thing:

When we create a new project with *meteor create appname* and then run it with *meteor run* Meteor automatically creates a simple project for us, right? (that simple app with a button and a counter).

Ok, based in the fact that all meteor project has his own mongodb associated, how can I take a look on the default db created? I´d like to use a command on console to check the collection structure created by default..

I´ve tried: show dbs | show collections | Mongo.Collection();

But always get the same error message: *use "new" to construct a Mongo.Collection.*

Yeah, I know that. I know how to create a new mongodb and then create a collection and insert values on it.

But what about that counter that is already working? It´s storaging his values in a collection already created, right?

I´d like to access it... and maybe modify.. not create one db for my own at this moment... How can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: The default skeleton app does not use mongo. You can try a more advanced demo app or add the mongo package yourself.

Answer (score 1):

`meteor mongo` command gives you access to mongo console.

From official documentation:

> **meteor mongo**
>
> Open a MongoDB shell on your local development database, so that you
>   can view or manipulate it directly.
>
> ...you must already have your application running locally with `meteor run`.

http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteormongo